# How can I get the usePrepareContractWrite to successfully create the write function with wagmi?

Tags: wagmi

I am following the wagmi doc to send a transaction to one of my smart contracts. But regardless of what I tried, the write function is not defined. I get no errors and the `prepareError` returns null. I don't know how to debug. I appreciated any tips.

Here is my component:

```
import {
  usePrepareContractWrite,
  useContractWrite,
  useWaitForTransaction,
  readContracts,
} from "wagmi";
import KillingTime from "../contracts/KillingTime.sol/KillingTime.json";
import KillingTimeMint from "../contracts/KillingTimeMint.sol/KillingTimeMint.json";

export default function UserInterface() {
  const [insurancePrice, setInsurancePrice] = useState(0);
  const [mintPrice, setMintPrice] = useState(0);
  const [insurance, setInsurance] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchInsurancePrice = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await readContracts({
          contracts: [
            {
              address: process.env
                .NEXT_PUBLIC_KT_MINT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS as `0x${string}`,
              abi: KillingTimeMint.abi,
              functionName: "_insurancePrice",
            },
          ],
        });
        setInsurancePrice(data[0].result as number);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    const fetchMintPrice = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await readContracts({
          contracts: [
            {
              address: process.env
                .NEXT_PUBLIC_KT_MINT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS as `0x${string}`,
              abi: KillingTimeMint.abi,
              functionName: "_price",
            },
          ],
        });
        setMintPrice(data[0].result as number);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    fetchInsurancePrice();
    fetchMintPrice();
  }, []);

  function handleChange() {
    setInsurance(!insurance);
  }

  const {
    config,
    error: prepareError,
    isError: isPrepareError,
  } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KT_MINT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS as `0x${string}`,
    abi: KillingTimeMint.abi,
    functionName: "mint",
    args: [insurance],
    value: BigInt(insurance ? mintPrice + insurancePrice : mintPrice),
    enabled: true,
  });

  const { data, write } = useContractWrite(config);
  console.log(write);
  const { isLoading, isSuccess } = useWaitForTransaction({
    hash: data?.hash,
  });

  return (
    <span className="grid align-center">
      <div className="mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChange} />
        <label className="mx-5">
          Add insurance for {Number(insurancePrice) / 10 ** 18} ETH
        </label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button className="border-solid border-2 p-2" onClick={() => write?.()}>
          {`Mint for ${
            insurance
              ? Number(mintPrice + insurancePrice) / 10 ** 18
              : Number(mintPrice) / 10 ** 18
          } ETH`}
        </button>
      </div>
    </span>
  );
}
```